# When chrome prevents credentials from being included in a URL request (in June 2017), how can php programmatically use basic auth?

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, authentication

If you use credentials in a URL from an AJAX request, you will be warned by Chrome browsers that passing credentials in a URL will be removed as of around the middle of 2017.
I need my PHP application to programmatically log a user in using Apache basic authentication based on the users' received SMS code. Is there a way to do this without using redirection?